# android get data from webview, an equivalent function to stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString in iphone

Tags: android

iam trying to build a class to get any data from webiew (this code is collected from many posts),
i need a function to do the same as "stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString" in iPhone

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    String RetValue = "";

public String ExecuteScript(WebView webv, String expression)
{
    RetValue = "";

    for (int t=0;t<2;t++)  // try loadUrl twice (incase the first call fails)
    {
        webv.loadUrl("javascript:var FunctionOne = function () { var res = " + expression + "; window.HTMLOUT.SendCallback(res); }; FunctionOne();");

        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) { // wait 3.5 seconds
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception exp) {

            }
            if (RetValue != "") return RetValue;  // if the browser returned a value return this value
        }
    }

    return RetValue; // if the loadUrl fails, the return value is empty string
}


@JavascriptInterface
public void SendCallback(String jsResult)
    {
        RetValue = jsResult;
    }
}
```

This function works most of times,
however, sometimes there is no return value (just like the script fails or something i dont know why)

is there a way to fix this code?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer in case someone has the same problem,
after days of searching i have successfully solved my problem:

1 - WebView init code should be like this

```
    webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webv);
    webv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { });

    javaInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
    webv.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "HTMLOUT");
```

2 - Do not add "setDomStorageEnabled" i dont know why it causes problems to the code above

3 - i was using this code for javascript alerts, but it seems that it causes problems too, so i had to remove it.

```
    webv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,           JsResult result) {
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
           }
    });
```

Now it is working better, however, sometimes i have to call the ExecuteScript multiple times to get the result.

i hope someone can explain this problem.